# ms access 2010 multiple queries per form

Tags: ms-access-2010

It's not entirely obvious on Access MS 2010, but is it possible for me to (using the IDE) choose a query to populate a label, choose another query to populate a textbox and another to populate a combo?

Thanks,

KS

Answer (score 0):

You can use various domain aggregate functions ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa168244(v=office.10).aspx ), which are similar to queries and you can run SQL in VBA and write results to the various controls. Combo row sources can be quite complex queries, if necessary.